# Selection appears in IE while writing summernote textarea

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea, summernote

I was wondering how the selection appears as showen in my image. I've no clue how to disable this selection and it only appears in IE browsers. The width is also strange as it's full width (text width) in other browsers.

Any advice, named element/function for this 'selection thing' would be welcome to make some steps in my debugging proces.

This is a summernote editor.

Example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Form #2 - Summernote editor
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol']],
      ['insert', ['hr']],
    ],
    height: 100,
    lang: 'nl-NL',
    onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
      $(this).val(contents);
      $(this).change();
    },
    onPaste: function(e) {
      var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
      e.preventDefault();
      document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
    }
  });



  // Form #2 - tabindex on Summernote
  $('.note-editable').ready(function() {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', 0);
  });

});
```

```css
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>


.note-editor {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c8cf;
  background: #fff;
}

.note-editor .note-dropzone {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  color: #87cefa;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px dashed #87cefa;
  opacity: .95;
  pointer-event: none;
}

.note-editor .note-dropzone .note-dropzone-message {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.note-editor .note-dropzone.hover {
  color: #098ddf;
  border: 2px dashed #098ddf
}

.note-editor.dragover .note-dropzone {
  display: table
}

.note-editor.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 100%
}

.note-editor.fullscreen .note-editable {
  background-color: white;
}

.note-editor.fullscreen .note-resizebar {
  display: none
}

.note-editor.codeview .note-editable {
  display: none
}

.note-editor.codeview .note-codable {
  display: block
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c8cf;
  padding: 5px 5px 4px 5px;
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar>.btn-group {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar>.btn-group .btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar>.btn-group .btn:hover,
.note-editor .note-toolbar>.btn-group .btn:focus {
  background: #E6E9ED;
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-table .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-table .dropdown-menu .note-dimension-picker {
  font-size: 18px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-table .dropdown-menu .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-mousecatcher {
  position: absolute!important;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  cursor: pointer
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-table .dropdown-menu .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-unhighlighted {
  position: relative!important;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASAgMAAAAroGbEAAAACVBMVEUAAIj4+Pjp6ekKlAqjAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfYAR0BKhmnaJzPAAAAG0lEQVQI12NgAAOtVatWMTCohoaGUY+EmIkEAEruEzK2J7tvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') repeat
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-table .dropdown-menu .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-highlighted {
  position: absolute!important;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASAgMAAAAroGbEAAAACVBMVEUAAIjd6vvD2f9LKLW+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfYAR0BKwNDEVT0AAAAG0lEQVQI12NgAAOtVatWMTCohoaGUY+EmIkEAEruEzK2J7tvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') repeat
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h1,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h2,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h3,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h4,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h5,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style h6,
.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-style blockquote {
  margin: 0
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-toggle {
  width: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 290px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group {
  margin: 0
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group:first-child {
  margin: 0 5px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-palette-title {
  margin: 2px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset {
  padding: 0 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset:hover {
  background: #eee
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-para .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 216px;
  padding: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar .note-para .dropdown-menu>div:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-statusbar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5
}

.note-editor .note-statusbar .note-resizebar {
  display: none;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: s-resize;
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9
}

.note-editor .note-statusbar .note-resizebar .note-icon-bar {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9
}

.note-editor .note-popover .popover {
  max-width: none
}

.note-editor .note-popover .popover .popover-content {
  padding: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-popover .popover .popover-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.note-editor .note-popover .popover .popover-content .btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px
}

.note-editor .note-popover .popover .arrow {
  left: 20px
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection>div {
  position: absolute
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-selection-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-opacity: .3;
  -khtml-opacity: .3;
  -moz-opacity: .3;
  opacity: .3;
  -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  filter: alpha(opacity=30)
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-handle {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-holder {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-sizing {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-nw {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-ne {
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: none
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-sw {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-se {
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: se-resize
}

.note-editor .note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-selection-info {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-opacity: .7;
  -khtml-opacity: .7;
  -moz-opacity: .7;
  opacity: .7;
  -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  filter: alpha(opacity=70)
}

.note-editor .note-dialog>div {
  display: none
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-image-dialog .note-dropzone {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 4;
  color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px dashed lightgray
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: #222!important;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: .9;
  -khtml-opacity: .9;
  -moz-opacity: .9;
  opacity: .9;
  -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  filter: alpha(opacity=90)
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .modal-content {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .title {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: white 1px solid
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .modal-close {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #dd0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .note-shortcut-layout {
  width: 100%
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .note-shortcut-layout td {
  vertical-align: top
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .note-shortcut {
  margin-top: 8px
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .note-shortcut th {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #dd0;
  text-align: left
}

.note-editor .note-dialog .note-help-dialog .note-shortcut td:first-child {
  min-width: 110px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  color: #dd0;
  text-align: right
}

.note-editor .note-editable {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 0
}

.note-editor .note-editable[contenteditable="false"] {
  background-color: #e5e5e5
}

.note-editor .note-codable {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #222;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 90px
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu.right::before {
  right: 9px;
  left: auto!important
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu.right::after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto!important
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu li a i {
  color: deepskyblue;
  visibility: hidden
}

.note-editor .dropdown-menu li a.checked i {
  visibility: visible
}

.note-editor .note-fontsize-10 {
  font-size: 10px
}

.note-editor .note-color-palette {
  line-height: 1
}

.note-editor .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff
}

.note-editor .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.note-editable {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable ol {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable ol li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable ul {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable ul li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#form form .form-col .note-editable hr {
  position: relative !important;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
}

.note-editor .note-toolbar i {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!-- form section -->
<div id="form" class="step-2">

  <form id="step_2" action="#" method="post">

    <div class="form-col">

      <!-- form row -->
      <div class="form-row untouched rnd-6 active">

        <!-- form group -->
        <p class="full-width">
          <label for="job_experiance" class="label">Label name</label>
          <span class="full">
            <textarea name="post_name[]" class="summernote" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
                 </span>
        </p>
        <!-- /form group -->

      </div>
      <!--/form row -->


    </div>

</div>

</form>

</div>
<!-- /form section -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.0/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This removes the outline styling which is applied to a textarea when it is in focus.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp)

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: I have added some test code, it's a bit raw but it do shows the problem when you play around a bit with the tekst editor.